# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Invalid Padding length: 190

Tags: java, security, ssl

We are using JRE 1.7 build 101 in our application. We are using SSL communication from our application to another Network Device. This network device will act as SSL server and our application connect as SSL Client.

We using https communication. Server enable TLSv1 and its used for SSL communication.

From Debug enabled below Cipher Suite used for this communication.
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

When we do test connectivity it works fine. But when we read huge amount of lines from Network Device we are getting below exception.

**javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Invalid Padding length: 190**

```
   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Invalid Padding length: 190

            at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)

            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)

            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)

            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)

            at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)

            at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)

            at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)

            at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)

            at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)

            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)

            at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)

            at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)

            at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)

            at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)

            at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)

            at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)

            at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)

            at SSLUtil.readFromInputStream(SSLUtil.java:205)
```

Any one faced this issue?? Any suggestion to debug this issue.
Each time Invalid Padding length: 190 ( this value is different)

Comment: Could you try with other crypto providers, for instance: BouncyCastle [https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html]

Comment: JRE default crypto only we are using. We can;t integrate any new thrid party now.

Comment: Why is there any defect in JRE 1.7 or any environment specific issue?

Comment: I do not know, it was just a way to figure out, was it an issue in JDK1.7 or it was an another one

Comment: do you have any idea that network bandwidth play in any role. Bez same JRE version we are not facing any issue in local with same config. Only in our customer environment we are facing this issue.

Comment: if so, then i'd suggest to check a JRE version (with `java --version`) of your customer first. then setup exactly the same JRE version locally and check it.

Comment: We had checked both are exactly same version and build

Comment: So, you have same JRE on both environments prod and local. Then you read a huge amount of lines from Network Device on both environments. And after that you have an error on prod, but do not have it on local environment, correct?

Comment: I'm not a sysadmin, but in case i understand it correctly, i would try to find a differences between systems. For instance, difference in MTU sizes, or your computers have little-endian architecture but your customer's servers have big-endian architecture.

Comment: after that you have an error on prod, but do not have it on local environment, correct?   yes... you are correct..

Comment: Could you please give more clarity how to check these MTU sizes and architecture..Then what is next step..I am grateful for your comments.

Comment: to check Endianess on linux machines : run from command line `lscpu | grep Endian` 
to check MTU on linux machines : run from command line `ifconfig` and check MTU from proper network interface (the network interface used by the software), for instance:
`eth1   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xxxx
          inet addr:xxx Bcast:xxx Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: ........
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  ` **MTU:1500** `Metric:1
          RX packets:......
          TX packets:.......`

Comment: In case there will be a diff in MTU, then try to setup the same value on your local env and do tests.
In case there will be a diff in Endian Arch, then try to switch to another  crypto providers.

Comment: both local & production we are using Windows 2012R2 server and we come to know that windows will support only little endian arch.

Comment: We will check the MTU as you suggested and proceed further. Will update you on the result. Thanks for spending time for me/

Comment: We checked in Customer setup and MTU size is same with local lab which is 1500. So we dont see any difference wrt MTU. Could you please suggest anything to proceed on this debugging. thanks